# Windows 8 multi monitor center mouse magnet

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors, mouse

Running Windows 8.1, two 1080p monitors. When I slowly move my mouse to the center of the two (left side of right monitor, right side of left monitor) regardless of vertical position it sticks, at that point I can try move it to the other monitor all I want but it won't untill I 'flick' it. The cursor moves up and down fine.

It's not the hot corners, I have those disabled through Start8. It's something else that's causing resistance in switching.

Any ideas on how to disable this would be cool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was [this](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/49401-sticky-edges-multi-monitors-enable-disable.html) regedit option;

> The .reg files below are for the registry key and value below.
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop
>   MouseMonitorEscapeSpeed DWORD
>   0 = enable
>   1 = disable

Answer (score 0):

I encoutered the same problem when I modifying the "Taskbar and Navigation properties". The mouse would not "jump" over to the other screen unless I moved it very fast.

When I checked the "Show taskbar on all displays"-box under the Taskbar-tab in the "Taskbar and Navigation properties"-window the problem was solved magicaly for me.

However the problem didn´t came back when I unchecked that box again so it could have been some other checkbox.